# xsl stylesheet and empty elements

Tags: xslt

i need to apply an xsl on a dublincore xml to convert

```
<dc:description> blahblah </dc:description>
```

in something like:

```
<descriptions>
 <description descriptionType="Abstract"> blahblah </description>
</descriptions>
```

i'm testing this, but if the element is empty 

i don't want to show anything, and not `<descriptions/>`

how should you correct this?

```
       <xsl:if test="dc:description">
            <descriptions>
                <xsl:for-each select="dc:description">
                <xsl:variable name="description" select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="$description !=''">
                    <description descriptionType="Abstract">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </description>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </descriptions>
        </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="dc:description/text()">
```

should be true only if there is at least one non-empty `dc:description`.  Or re-use the same test you do in the inner if and say

```
<xsl:if test="dc:description != ''">
```

a `!=` test where one side is a node set succeeds if there is *any* node in the set whose value is `!=` the other side (which is why there's a note in the spec that `x != y` is not necessarily the same as `not(x = y)` if either or both of x and y are node sets).